# Бесконечный цикл и выполнить запуск метода один раз при обнаружение

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь сделать программу которая будет отслеживать запуск определённых процессов, если какой-то процесс запустился отследить его и запустить метод (функции) Затем если процессы закрылись продолжать искать появление нужных процессов, и.т.п

Для одного поиска сделал так:

```
IntPtr ptr = WinAPI.FindWindow(null, "notepad");
while (ptr == IntPtr.Zero) 
{
    if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)  
    { 
       Console.WriteLine("окно не найдено"); 
       // Если окно не нашли то возвращаемся к поиску.
    }
    else 
    { 
       Если нашли то делаем что либо:
       Console.WriteLine("окно найдено"); 
       StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder(100); 
       Console.WriteLine(st.ToString()); 
    } 
}
```

Для списка же процессов добавил `List<string>` со списком процессов которые нужно проверять на запуск через `FindWindow`.

```
private static readonly List<string> App = new List<string>
{
  "Notepad",
  "Notepad++",
  "Блокнот",
  "Word",
};
```

И в цикле прогоняю их

```
for (int i = 0; i < App.Count; i++)
{
   IntPtr ptr = WinAPI.FindWindow(null, App[i]);
   while (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
   {
     if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
     {
       Console.WriteLine("окно не найдено");
       Thread.Sleep(500);
       // Если окно не нашли то возвращаемся к поиску.
     }
     Console.WriteLine("окно найдено");
      // Как сделать следующее?
     // Если окно найдено, то Один раз выполнить какое-то действие.
    // И ждать пока окно не закроется.
     //Если окно закрылось возвратиться к поиску.
     var st = new StringBuilder(100);
     Console.WriteLine(st.ToString());
   }
}
```

Вопрос:
Как сделать запуск функции метода один раз за проходы в цикле `for` ?

И ещё если окон нет запущенных то он всё равно пишет что окно найдено ( скрин )[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить?

Comment: За что минусы ставите?

Comment: `Как сделать запуск функции метода один раз за проходы в цикле for` как это понимать?

Comment: вы запускаете `while (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)` но внутри цикла не меняете `ptr`, то есть цикл получается бесконечный и ничего не делающий.

Comment: Попробую включить экстасенса, вам нужно при обнаружении любой программы из списка что-то выполнить, это верно? Вы понимаете, что если программа запущена, то это что-то будет выполняться постоянно, если конечно необходимое действие не заключается в закрытии искомой программы? Ну а чтобы исправить вывод "окно найдено" просто уберите этот вывод в блок else, как в вашем первом примере.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<IntPtr> pointers = new List<IntPtr>();
for (int i = 0; i < App.Count; i++)
  pointers.Add(IntPtr.Zero);

while (true) {
  for (int i = 0; i < App.Count; i++)
  {
    IntPtr ptr = WinAPI.FindWindow(null, App[i]);
    Console.WriteLine(ptr == IntPtr.Zero? "окно не найдено: {0}" : "окно найдено: {0}", App[i]);
    if (pointers[i] != ptr) {
      if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero && pointers[i] != IntPtr.Zero)
        Console.WriteLine("  process restarted");
      else if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
        Console.WriteLine("  process ended");
      else if (pointers[i] == IntPtr.Zero)
        Console.WriteLine("  process started");
      pointers[i] = ptr;
    }
  }
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: @Luser Я не понимаю, что это значит. В ответе нет ни одного "метода". Напишите по-русски, что Вам нужно.

Comment: @Luser *"по-русски" пишется, как в моем комментарии ).* Допустим, и что? Откуда взялся этот метод, и где он вызывается?

Comment: Забейте, ничего не нужно, вы всё ровно не понимаете